# Vue: Array length conditional in dynamic class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am cycling through a Firestore collection Colours, and want to use a conditional dynamic class based on the length of array attribute alpha.

I tried:

```
<v-card v-for="Colour in Colours" :key="Colour.id">
  <v-text-field v-model="Colour.alpha" :value="Colour.alpha" :class="Colour.alpha.length >= '1' ? 'greenClass' : 'blueClass'"></v-text-field>
```

Which didn't work, and have been searching for an answer, the only relevant suggestion I could find as this:

```
v-bind:class="{ 'greenClass': Colour.alpha.length >= 1 }"
```

which also did not work.

Is it possible to use `.length` like this?

Also, I would like to have multiple conditional classes, eg.

```
Colour.alpha.length == 0 -> assign class 'white'
Colour.alpha.length == 1 -> assign class 'blue'
Colour.alpha.length == 2 -> assign class 'green'
Colour.alpha.length >= 3 -> assign class 'red'
```

But I have a feeling this is even less likely to be possible (at least I have no idea how to implement that)

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding CSS classes you need to use either [object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) or [array syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax)

1. <s>Your 1st example is neither so it doesn't work</s> Passing just a string actually works just fine...
2. Your 2nd example looks like correct usage of class syntax and should work. Most probable reason it doesn't is `Colour.alpha` is not always assigned (`undefined` or `null` instead of empty array `[]`). So check your data...

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      Colours: [
       { id: 1, alpha: [1, 2, 3]},
       { id: 2, alpha: [1, 2]},
       { id: 3, alpha: [1]},
       { id: 4, alpha: []}
      ],
      alphaToClass: ['white', 'blue', 'green', 'red']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getColorClass(alpha) {
      const index = alpha ? Math.min(alpha.length, 3) : 0
      return this.alphaToClass[index]    
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.white {
  background-color: white
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue
}

.green {
  background-color: green
}

.red {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div v-for="Colour in Colours" :key="Colour.id">
    <input type="text" v-model="Colour.alpha" :class="getColorClass(Colour.alpha)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, human error on this one, I was editing code for one section of my work and expecting changes in another section. Totally my mistake! The 1st example does actually seem to be working now on my code. Thank you for you reply

Comment: Thank you very much @Michal! Your edit with the getColorClass() works perfectly. I didn't even think to use a method like that to determine class.